# Why does Ubuntu One Files for Android app create an entry in the 'Accounts and Sync' section of the Android settings menu?

Tags: ubuntu-one, android

I have the Ubuntu One app for Android and its works perfectly fine but there always has been something that confused me. In my phones main **Settings** menu in the **Accounts and Sync** section Ubuntu One has created an entry:

[image]

However it isn't possible to turn the Sync on like can be seen on the Google account above it, also there are no entries when you click on the Ubuntu One Account:

[image]

In comparison the Google sync account has lots of options:

[image]

So why has Ubuntu One created this account? Is it there for potential future functions which have not yet been implemented or is there another reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The account entry is there to store your Ubuntu One credentials.  This has two benefits:

1. You can delete your credentials from the phone the same way you would for any other account.
2. Multiple applications can use the same credentials to access your data on Ubuntu One rather than each application having to request access independently.